# stop enter from going new record access 2007 vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form (split form) and i want to prevent access from creating a new record when the user reaches the final field of form and hit the enter key. I already tried to change the **Cycle** property in the **Other** tab and didn't work

By split form i mean a form that has **Split Form** on **Default View** in the **Format** tab

Comment: What do you mean by "split form"?  Changing **Cycle** is the way to accomplish what you are asking, so I suspect that perhaps you have a more complicated form that is built on subforms.

Answer (score 2):

On Access Form,

```
Form.AllowAdditions = False
```

Will forbide adding new record.

You can set this property in both the design view and at the running time.